# Example code of "Type Aliases" to work

Tags: typescript

The example code below is from [the Handbook of TypeScript official site](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases).  It just describes how its style is something like and does not work.  Is actual code to work so complicated?  I have no idea how to type a property as the same type as itself (type LinkedList = T & { next: LinkedList }).

```
type LinkedList<T> = T & { next: LinkedList<T> };

interface Person {
    name: string;
}

var people: LinkedList<Person>;
var s = people.name;
var s = people.next.name;
var s = people.next.next.name;
var s = people.next.next.next.name;
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to implement a type like this with strict null checking (responding to @artem).  You don't have to make it *actually* infinite, only *potentially* infinite... such as *circular*.  For example:

```
type LinkedList<T> = T & { next: LinkedList<T> };

interface Person {
  name: string;
}

// new LLP("name") produces a circular LinkedList<Person>
class LLP implements LinkedList<Person> {
  public next: LinkedList<Person>;
  constructor(public name: string, next?: LinkedList<Person>) {
    this.next = next ? next : this;
  }
}

var people: LinkedList<Person> = new LLP("Alice", new LLP("Bob", new LLP("Carol"));
console.log(people.name); // Alice
console.log(people.next.name); // Bob
console.log(people.next.next.name); // Carol
console.log(people.next.next.next.name); // Also Carol
console.log(people.next.next.next.next.name); // Forever Carol
```

I agree it's a weird type; usually you'd give a way to bail out by having `next` be optional, as @artem indicates.

Comment: Yes, my 'impossible to create' is qualified with 'unless mutation is allowed somehow' - because  until `this.next` is initialized in constructor, it does not conform to the type

Comment: It's not mutating the type, just the contents, which is how constructors work.  Saying it doesn't conform to the type until the constructor initializes the instance is a bit strange.  Do you have the same objection to other constructors that initialize properties?

Comment: And does this count as mutation to you?  `const circle: LinkedList<Person> = { name: "Circle", get next() { return this; } }`

Comment: Technically yes because the implementation must do the equivalent of  `Object.defineProperty(...)` which is a mutation. However it's hidden well enough behind the nice abstraction and is not likely to cause any problems, unlike the fact that the object does not conform to its type until the constructor finishes. In the latter case, you should be careful about calling any method from a constructor that relies on `this` conforming to its type.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I tried your code and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

> I have no idea how to type a property as the same type as itself (type LinkedList = T & { next: LinkedList }).

```
type LinkedList<T> = T & { next: LinkedList<T> };
```

This example assumes that `--strictNullChecks` is turned off, otherwise it's indeed impossible to create and object like this without violating type constraints - this type describes an infinite data structure if `next` is not allowed to be `undefined`.

But if you declare `next` as either a reference to the next item in the list or `undefined`, everything is fine:

```
type LinkedList<T> = T & { next: LinkedList<T> | undefined };

type Person = { name: string };

const personList: LinkedList<Person> =
        { name: 'Head', next: { name: 'Last', next: undefined } };
```

Comment: You actually can implement the original `LinkedList<Person>` with strict null checks in a type safe way, if it matters.